# CodeIgniter img tag

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using following code to display an image with CodeIgniter framework.

```
<?php echo img('sample/logo.png'); ?>
```

And this is producing following output::

```
<img alt="" src="http://localhost:8080/test/css/sample/logo.png">
```

Why it does not closes the tag with `/>`
Also, how can i specify the `alt` text when i echo image?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img), it should end with />. I tried it out, and it works.

If you want a shorter tag, use this:

```
<?php echo img(array('src'=>'image/picture.jpg', 'alt'=> 'alt information')); ?>
```

Sometimes if you view source using certain browsers (firefox, chrome), it omits the /> tag. Try view source using a notepad or something, it should display proper /> tag.

Comment: Indeed. It's clearly there in the source code for the helper as well. @Roman: I found this really annoying, so I created `MY_html_helper.php` and modified the `img()` code to accept the alt text as the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
$image_properties = array(
          'src' => 'sample/logo.png',
          'alt' => 'Me, demonstrating how to eat 4 slices of pizza at one time',
          'class' => 'post_images',
          'width' => '200',
          'height' => '200',
          'title' => 'That was quite a night',
          'rel' => 'lightbox',
);

img($image_properties);
// <img src="http://site.com/index.php/sample/logo.png" alt="Me, demonstrating how to eat 4 slices of pizza at one time" class="post_images" width="200" height="200" title="That was quite a night" rel="lightbox" />
```

reference : http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img

Answer (score -2):

Dont echo an image like that, do it like this:

```
echo "<img src='sample/logo.png' alt='my company name' title='my company logo' border='0' />";
```

Remeber the location you have there is relative, you should try to stick to absolute paths were possible eg: "/test/css/sample/logo.png" to avoid confusion.

(sorry, missed the bit where you said you were using a framework).

Comment: Yes, your code will work. But, @Roman asked, how can he achieve through codeignator only?. ;). You know, another very simplest format just put the html code in your php file. <img src='sample/logo.png' alt='my company name' title='my company logo' border='0' /> :-)